# Change the background color according to the status of the Room in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

Since I am new to the Xamarin and I am building basically meeting room app.
I want to change the background color of my page by checking the current time with booking time.
If there is no booking for the particular time,it should show AVAILABLE and show green color and similarly, If there is any booking for the current time,it should show BOOKED an show red color.

Please help me to get through this.

Comment: Where is your code?  What have you tried?  You can't just give us a list of requirements and expect us to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for an IValueConverter. However, your requirement is very abstract. Please be specific so that it can be helped more.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters#the-ivalueconverter-interface

Refer to the above link to know more about converters. All you need to do is to write a converter for the Background color and write your business logic there.

```
BackgroundColor="{Binding Converter={StaticResource YourConverterResourceHere}}" />
```